# How does one declare a scalar variable?

Tags: c#, sql, xml, ado.net

I'm trying to make a update so that i can upload data from an XML file to SQL Server. However, the following exception is thrown `Must declare the scalar variable...`.  I think I've declared the required variables.  I have checked about 10 times, but I can't see where I've gone wrong. Can you? If yes, please provide an edit of my code with the answer and an explanation of where I've gone wrong. Thank you for helping and for your time.

```
sqltext="SET IDENTITY_INSERT HomeCareVisit ON update HomeCareVisit set PatientNo=@PatientNo,ScheduledDateTime= @ScheduledDateTime,TreatmentInstructions=@TreatmentInstructions, MedicalStaffID=@MedicalStaffID, Priority=@Priority,ActualVisitDateTime=@ActualVisitDateTime,TreatmentProvided=@TreatmentProvided,Prescription=@Prescription,AdvisoryNotes=@AdvisoryNotes,FurtherVisitRequired=@FurtherVisitRequired where VisitRefNo=@VisitRefNo";

SqlCommand Insertcommand = new SqlCommand(sqltext, conn);
//SqlCommand Insertcommand = new SqlCommand( "SET IDENTITY_INSERT HomeCareVisit ON update HomeCareVisit set PatientNo=@PatientNo,ScheduledDateTime= @ScheduledDateTime,TreatmentInstructions=@TreatmentInstructions, MedicalStaffID=@MedicalStaffID, Priority=@Priority,ActualVisitDateTime=@ActualVisitDateTime,TreatmentProvided=@TreatmentProvided,Prescription=@Prescription,AdvisoryNotes=@AdvisoryNotes,FurtherVisitRequired=@FurtherVisitRequired where VisitRefNo=@VisitRefNo");

adpter.InsertCommand = Insertcommand;
adpter.InsertCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();

try
{
    using (Insertcommand)
    {                         
        Insertcommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PatientNo", PatientNo);
        Insertcommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FurtherVisitRequired", FurtherVisitRequired);
        Insertcommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@AdvisoryNotes", AdvisoryNotes);
        Insertcommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Prescription", Prescription);
        Insertcommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TreatmentProvided", TreatmentProvided);
        Insertcommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ActualVisitDateTime",ActualVisitDateTime);
        Insertcommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Priority", Priority);
        Insertcommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ScheduledDateTime", ScheduledDateTime);
        Insertcommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TreatmentInstructions", TreatmentInstructions);
        Insertcommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@MedicalStaffID", MedicalStaffID);

        Insertcommand.ExecuteNonQuery();

        MessageBox.Show("updated");
    }

}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
}

conn.Close();
MessageBox.Show("Done .. ");
```

Comment: Which scalar variable does it tell you you need to declare?

Comment: @PatientNo but as you can see from the code it's the very first one i declared.

Comment: Are you saying that the error message is that the @PatientNo variable isn't declared?

Comment: Yes. That is what the exception states.

Comment: What is the value and type of `PatientNo` when the `AddWithValue()` method is called? You've probably got a non-scalar type of data, or `AddWithValue()` is interpreting it that way.

Comment: Then you should include that in the question.

Comment: I'm likely mistaken, but I'm not sure you have to put the "@" in the AddWithValue() call. Have you tried without?

Comment: @Medinoc This [sample](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparametercollection.addwithvalue.aspx) shows that @ is expected.

Comment: Does the SQL work in SSMS? If you just run the SQL text with a bunch of "DECLARE @PatientNo INT = 1" statements at the top to set up the parameters, you can test the query out in isolation. That has to be the first step, then you can at least tick that off the list and go on to why it doesn't work in code

Comment: `IDENTITY_INSERT` *only* affects `INSERT` statements. You cannot `UPDATE` an identity column, if that's what you were aiming for.

Comment: @KeithPayne PatientNo = Convert.ToInt32(ds.Tables[0].Rows[i].ItemArray[1]); which is taking information from the xml file. It is type of int

McKay I'll take that under advisement for future reference.

Medinoc If I'm not mistaken without the '@' it's not parameter.

Comment: @KeithPayne - It is optional. Both work.

Answer (score 2):

The main issue is that

```
adpter.InsertCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Happens before the parameters get added. I'm not particularly familiar with data adapters but I guess you should just delete that line as you call

```
Insertcommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

later on anyway.

Once you fix that your SQL is

```
SET IDENTITY_INSERT HomeCareVisit ON;

UPDATE HomeCareVisit
SET    PatientNo = @PatientNo,
       ScheduledDateTime = @ScheduledDateTime,
       TreatmentInstructions = @TreatmentInstructions,
       MedicalStaffID = @MedicalStaffID,
       Priority = @Priority,
       ActualVisitDateTime = @ActualVisitDateTime,
       TreatmentProvided = @TreatmentProvided,
       Prescription = @Prescription,
       AdvisoryNotes = @AdvisoryNotes,
       FurtherVisitRequired = @FurtherVisitRequired
WHERE  VisitRefNo = @VisitRefNo
```

But you aren't passing `@VisitRefNo` in as a parameter. You need to.

Also the `SET IDENTITY_INSERT` is pointless for an `UPDATE` statement.

Comment: thank you for spotting that. However it has not solved the problem. I'm still getting the same exception.

Comment: "Must declare the scalar variable "@PatientNo"" was the message before removing that line, it has shifted to ""Must declare the scalar variable "@VisitRefNo"".

Comment: @GeorgeIanGuyMarsden - Also get rid of the `adpter.InsertCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();` before you add the parameters.