# ADO.Net c# 0x80131904 must declare scalar variable/function

Tags: c#, sql, ado.net

I'm trying to use a function via a SQL connection I've done everywhere else in my application (only here it give the error, not the rest of the application). When i searched for what that error code meant the responses i found say it's an error when one can't connect to SQL server? but it doesn't give a solution.

here is my c# code

```
 SqlConnection connection = Database.GetConnection();

                DataTable dt = new DataTable("CRC");
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT dbo.CalcRentalCharge(@RentalStartDateTime,@RentalEndDateTime,@CarTypeID)", connection);
            try
        {
            connection.Open();
            using (SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
            {
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@RentalStartDateTimetext", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = RentalStartDateTimeBox.Text;
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@RentalEndDateTimetext", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = RentalEndDateTimeBox.Text;
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@CarTypeIDtext", SqlDbType.Int).Value = CarTypeID.Text;

                connection.Open();
                Decimal rentalChange = (Decimal)cmd.ExecuteScalar();
                connection.Close();
                MessageBox.Show("The rental change is: " + rentalChange.ToString());

                if (dr.HasRows)
                {
                    dt.Load(dr);
                    dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
                }
            }
            connection.Close();
```

Can you help me get this FUNCTION to work?

Comment: You are making the same mistake [as yesterday](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18465417/how-does-one-declare-a-scalar-variable). You `ExecuteReader` before adding the parameters.

Comment: @MartinSmith even executing the reader after the parameters have been added is giving the same exception.

Comment: Well there is also the other issue that the names are wrong anyway pointed out by nvoigt

Comment: he did and i sorted that out. Still same error.

Answer (score 2):

Don't use `cmd.ExecuteReader()` before adding parameter to command object.
It gives error,
add parameter to command and then cmd.execureReader()

Comment: even executing the reader after the parameters have been added is giving the same exception.

Answer (score 1):

You have a copy/paste error in your variable name:

In the line

> cmd.Parameters.Add("@RentalStartDateTimetext", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = RentalStartDateTimeBox.Text;

the string

> RentalStartDateTimetext

needs to be

> RentalStartDateTime

In addition to that, because it will pop up as your next error: Your opening and closing of the connection is wrong. Use a using block for the connection as well and open it directly after the start of the block. You don't need to close it manually, the using-block will do that for you.

Comment: you mean like this?

using (connection)
                {connection.Open();
                    DataTable dt = new DataTable("CRC");
  
                    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@RentalStartDateTime", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = RentalStartDateTimeBox.Text;
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@RentalEndDateTime", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = RentalEndDateTimeBox.Text;
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@CarTypeID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = CarTypeID.Text;
                    Decimal rentalChange = (Decimal)cmd.ExecuteScalar();